# Trouble with accessing the DB in Laravel 4.2

Tags: php, laravel-4.2

I am trying to add a new environment for my Laravel (4.2) project but i have this error:

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No route to host

Which generates in: ­`vendor/­laravel/­framework/­src/­Illuminate/­Database/­Connectors/Connector.php`

I believe the reason is that i did not set up the environment correctly, even though i followed all the steps in the Laravel documentation.

Did anyone got the error before? Or is aware of why it is happening?

I will provide any data needed in order to solve this, i'm just not sure what to provide at the moment since i have no clue about what causes this.

Thanks.

Comment: what you are using as your database host to connect with the database?

Comment: @MuhammadSumonMollaSelim In this case (since it's dev) i am using the localhost, which is defined in the app/config/{my-env-name}/database.php

Comment: can you see if your mysql server is running and available from localhost? your error means mysql can't be connected on localhost.

Comment: @MuhammadSumonMollaSelim The mysql is running since i already have couple of environments in this project on this server that are running with the same settings and they are working like a charm. The problem is with this environment only

Answer (score 0):

I actually found out what the problem was.

In order for Laravel to read your environment name (for example: dev) you will need to make the user "dev" be the owner of the entire project.

I had this issue since the owner of the project was "root" and Laravel couldn't find a config for the "root" environment since i never created a "root" folder and configurations in app -> config.